# Change default launcher on button click ANDROID

Tags: java, android, buttonclick, android-launcher

I have this code in my manifest which allows me to set different activities in my application as the launcher. Is there a way that I can implement a button  so that on button click it allows me to change the default launcher? For example, when I set the default launcher as settings activity, home activity can't be set as the default. I want the option to change it.

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />                
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".HomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:stateNotNeeded="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PackageManager to disable/enable each of your app components but perhaps it would be simpler to stick to one entry point in your app (like `StartActivity` with no UI (i.e. themed `Theme.NoDisplay`) which would then call `startActivity()` on the right one depending on user config.

Comment: My application has 2 launchers provided so the user can change which one they want to use. Could you provide me an example using packagemanager this way?